# How to schedule task to run in background using django background tasks

Tags: django, django-models

I have set up a background task "date_check" but it does not run daily. I can't figure out where I've went wrong in the setup. I also got the error "`TypeError: date_check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` when I tried to run `python manage.py process_tasks`.

here is my model.py:

```py
...
    @background(schedule=5)
    def date_check(self):
        """Will be used as a background task to make sure trips that have ended don't hog van availability."""
        today = datetime.date.today()
        name = self.van_used
        if today > self.trip_start and today > self.trip_end:
            vans.objects.filter(vanName = name).update(available = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.date_check(repeat=Task.DAILY)
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried removing self from the function parameter, still to no avail. I am now getting the error `TypeError: date_check() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'van_used', 'trip_start', and 'trip_end'`.
Here's the updated code:

```
    @background(schedule=5)
    def date_check(van_used, trip_start, trip_end):
        """Will be used as a background task to make sure trips that have ended don't hog van availability."""
        today = datetime.date.today()
        name = van_used
        if today > trip_start and today > trip_end:
            vans.objects.filter(vanName = name).update(available = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.date_check(self.van_used, self.trip_start, self.trip_end, repeat=Task.DAILY)
```

Comment: You can not use `self` here. Such processes are "standalones". You can however, of course fetch all `Vans` and then perform the processing.

Comment: Ok, I’m a bit confused on how to do that without accessing self. Would I just query for all of the van objects and then call my “date_check” function on each of them?

Answer (score 0):

In order to actually run the function, it (of course) needs the arguments. There is, however, not really a position in your code that calls it (since its scheduled), meaning there is not really a position in your code where you can actually pass the arguments. This is also what Willem meant in his reply when he mentioned it was a "standalone", you don't call it yourself. Since python doesn't know what to pass but is asked to give vars, it throws an exception.

The answer: find a way to retrieve the argument within the function. Make the signature arg-free. I'm guessing the "self" in your original post is a "Van"-object, so you'd get something like this:

```
    def date_check():
    """Will be used as a background task to make sure trips that have ended don't hog van availability."""
    van = vans.objects.all() # or some appropriate filter
    today = datetime.date.today()
    for v in van:
        name = van.van_used
        if today > van.trip_start and today > van.trip_end:
            vans.objects.filter(vanName = name).update(available = True)
```

There's not really a way to make a background task execute on all vans individually (not one that I know of at least) but this should give you the same result